# How to compress each subfolder in a folder into separate RAR archives with rar.exe using a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, winrar

I have multiple folders inside `N:\working`.

- `N:\working\1`
- `N:\working\2`
- `N:\working\3`

I want to RAR compress them all individually on 64-bit Windows.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD N:\working

SET rar_executable=C:\Rar.exe
ECHO  Using WinRAR executable: %rar_executable%

ECHO.
%rar_executable% a -r -ep1 -m0 "Test.rar"

pause
```

It produces the file `Test.rar` containing all three folders. But I want to archive the three folders into the archive files `1.rar`, `2.rar` and `3.rar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That task can be done with a batch file containing only a single command line.

```
@for /D %%I in ("N:\working\*") do @"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 -r -- "%%I.rar" "%%I\"
```

The same command line for usage in a command prompt window without using a batch file:

```
for /D %I in ("N:\working\*") do "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 -r -- "%I.rar" "%I\"
```

There is no `@` left to `for` as that would be completely useless on running this command line in a command prompt window. `@` left to `Rar.exe` with full qualified file name is removed to see the command line output by `cmd.exe` when a new archive file creation starts.

**FOR** searches in specified directory `N:\working` for non-hidden subdirectories and assigns the full qualified directory name to loop variable `I` before executing `Rar.exe` for this subdirectory.

`Rar.exe` adds (`a`) recursively (`-r`) all directories and files in the subdirectory found by **FOR** to a RAR archive file with name of the current subdirectory and file extension `.rar` created in the specified directory `N:\working` using best compression (`-m5`) without any output to console window and ignoring all errors (`-inul`) which could occur during folder compression. The standard configuration is ignored (`-cfg-`) on compression. The name of the compressed subdirectory with its path is not added to the RAR archive file (`-ep1` and folder to compress ends with a backslash).

Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, run `for /?` and read the output help explaining option `/D` (directory search).

Open text file `Rar.rxt` in program files folder of *WinRAR* with a double click which is the manual of `Rar.exe` explaining the command `a` and the switches used here.

This task could be also done with `WinRAR.exe` using a profile created before with starting `WinRAR.exe` with the profile name as only option on the command line stored in a shortcut file. This solution would not open a console window because of `WinRAR.exe` is a Windows GUI desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

try this script as a .bat file which will compress each folder as a RAR file within the current directory and also will show some additional detail which is very useful while compressing a large size of data.

**.Bat File Script**

```
@echo off
@for /D %%I in (".\*")  do echo started at %date% %time% compressing... "%%I" && @"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 -r -- "%%I.rar" "%%I\" 
echo "Completed Successfully !!!"
pause
```

**Sample Outout**

[image]